# Convert 4 bytes char to int32 in C

Tags: c

I first convert an int32 number to char[4] array, then convert the array back to int32 by (int *), but the number isn't the same as before:

```
unsigned int num = 2130706432;
unsigned int x;
unsigned char a[4];

a[0] = (num>>24) & 0xFF;
a[1] = (num>>16) & 0xFF;
a[2] = (num>>8) & 0xFF;
a[3] = num & 0xFF;

x = *(int *)a;
printf("%d\n", x);
```

the output is 127. And if I set num = 127, the output is 2130706432.
Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Is your platform little endian or big endian?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness  The byte order for an int on your platform is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: @Eric J. oh i forgot this. Now it's solved, thank you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it's tagged C.

Comment: @zwx: I think `x = *(int *)a;` violates strict-aliasing rules (try to compile with warnings enabled), in modern C you should use a union to do type-punning (but it's best to do it via bit-shifting). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143857/bad-value-affectation-after-type-casting/8159802#8159802

Comment: @ninjalj: Exactly. The code is actually UB. The correct way to go about this is to reverse the order: `unsigned int x; unsigned char * a = (unsigned char*)(&x);`

Comment: @ninjalj: Using unions for type punning is *also undefined behavior*.  You can't safely read from an inactive member of the union.

Comment: @BenVoigt: In C99 it's not UB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511676/portable-data-reinterpretation

Comment: Ahh, right, my earlier comment is based on the C++ rules.  Sorry.  (Although C did have such a rule, it was designated as a defect, as mentioned in the answers to the question @ninjalj linked)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reverse the order of the a[] indexes, e.g,. a[0] -> a[3]

I think you have the endianness in reverse.

Try this:

```
a[3] = (num>>24) & 0xFF;
a[2] = (num>>16) & 0xFF;
a[1] = (num>>8) & 0xFF;
a[0] = num & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 10):

To see what happens use

```
printf("%x\n", ...);
```

to print both input and output number.

Endian-independent way:

```
x = (a[0] << 24) | (a[1] << 16) | (a[2] << 8) | a[3];
```

Comment: I don't know why this is voted up. As if it's an endian-independent way, it should work on my PC too. But I have to do quite the opposite `uint32_t var2 = (v[3]  << 24) | (v[2] << 16) | (v[1] << 8) | v[0];`

Comment: I use `vector<unsigned char>` and fill it with `uint32_t` vars using `memcpy`: `memcpy(&v[0], &var, sizeof var);`

Comment: @rightaway717 So save it in endianess of your computer. To do it endian-independent way you have to convert uint32_t -> array as OP does and array -> uint32_t as I do.

Answer (score 6):

This line is never going to work correctly on a little-endian machine:

```
x = *(int *)a;
```

You need to unpack the data before you print out the value.

Comment: Additionally, it may not work on big-endian machines with compilers that take advantage of strict-aliasing rules.

Answer (score 5):

Your code `a[0] = (num>>24) & 0xFF;` takes the most significant 8 bits from `num` and sticks them in the first byte of `a`. On little endian machines the first byte holds the least signficant bits. That means that on little endian machines, this code takes the most significant 8 bits and stores them in the place where the least significant bits go, changing the value.

2130706432 is 0x7F000000 in hex, and 127 is 0x0000007F.

Also, `x = *(int *)a;` results in undefined behavior. Consider hardware where reading an int from an improperly aligned address causes a bus error. If `a` doesn't happen to be aligned properly for an int then the program would crash.

A correct approach to interpreting the bytes as an `int` would be `std::memcpy(&x, a, sizeof x);`