# Converting 4bytes to signed and unsigned ints

Tags: c++, int

I want to convert a four-byte string to either `int32` or `uint32` in c++. 
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173037/convert-4-bytes-char-to-int32-in-c) helped me to write the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    std::string a("\xaa\x00\x00\xaa", 4);

    int u = *(int *) a.c_str();
    int v = *(unsigned int *) a.c_str();
    int x = *(int32_t *) a.c_str();
    int y = *(uint32_t *) a.c_str();
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int: " << u << std::endl;
    std::cout << "uint: " << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int32_t: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "uint32_t: " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However the outputs are all the same, where the `int` (or `int32_t`) values are correct, but the unsigned ones are wrong. Why does not the unsigned conversions work?

```
// output
int:      -1442840406
uint:     -1442840406
int32_t:  -1442840406
uint32_t: -1442840406
```

Pythons `struct.unpack`, gives the right conversion

```
In [1]: import struct
In [2]: struct.unpack("<i", b"\xaa\x00\x00\xaa")
Out[2]: (-1442840406,)
In [3]: struct.unpack("<I", b"\xaa\x00\x00\xaa")
Out[3]: (2852126890,)
```

I would also like a similar solution to work for `int16` and `uint16`, but first things first, since I guess an extension would be trivial if I manage to solve this problem.

Comment: Because you're placing them all in (signed) `int` variables.

Comment: Ahhh! How stupid of me... Been pulling my hair for hours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the unsigned values in an unsigned variables and it will work:

```c++
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    std::string a("\xaa\x00\x00\xaa", 4);

    int u = *(int *) a.c_str();
    unsigned int v = *(unsigned int *) a.c_str();
    int32_t x = *(int32_t *) a.c_str();
    uint32_t y = *(uint32_t *) a.c_str();
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int: " << u << std::endl;
    std::cout << "uint: " << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << "int32_t: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "uint32_t: " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When you cast the value to unsigned and then store it in a signed variable, the compiler plays along.  Later, when you print the signed variable, the compiler generates code to print a signed variable output.

Comment: Great!  The biggest risk of being lazy and just copy-paste rows... Thanks!