# Correct way for interpreting one type as another?

Tags: c

Say I have a `float` that I want to interpret as an `unsigned int` for some bit-twiddling (let's assume `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)` for now). Now there are various ways that "work", for example:

```
float f = 0.5f;
unsigned int u;

u = * (unsigned int*) (&var); /* works in most compilers */

union {
    float f;
    unsigned int u;
} uconv;

uconv.f = f;
u = uconv.u; /* works in most compilers */
```

Now I don't know the standard by heart, but IIRC the first is undefined behaviour thanks to the strict aliasing rule and I heard that the latter is undefined behaviour too.

So what is the correct, defined way to interpret the value of one type as if it was another type?

---

Please add to your answer whether it works for C89, C90, C99 or even C11.

Comment: Take a look in `/usr/include/ieee754.h` for a better way of declaring the union.

Comment: @Paul R: sorry, I don't have that header file. But I know that if I can assume IEEE754 that I should use a union with two `uint32_t`'s depending on endianness in a particular union for a `double`.

Comment: Example here: http://www.emdebian.org/~zumbi/test/gcc-4.6-4.6.1/build/ieee754.h

Comment: @Paul R: that requires bitfields, which not all compilers support.

Comment: Huh - can you tell me which C or C++ compiler does not support bit fields ? They have always been part of both C and C++ AFAIK.

Comment: Paul R: IIRC bitfields were not introduced into C until C99.

Comment: No - bit fields go back as far as K & R.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143857/bad-value-affectation-after-type-casting, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule ,  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_283.htm

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511676/portable-data-reinterpretation-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the correct way is to cast the variable's address to `void*`, `char*` or `unsigned char*`, because any other pointer cast may cause undefined behavior (indeed, because of [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)). `int*` and `float*` are incompatible pointer types.

When the `sizeof` both types is the same, the following will work:

```
memcpy(&u, &var, sizeof(int));  // note: implicit conversion to void [const] *
```

The value that you get is obviously implementation-defined, since it depends on how both `int` and `float` are represented in memory.

Strict aliasing has been around [since C89](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6514750/166749).

**EDIT**: seems I was wrong previously about the `union` hack causing UB. The relevant part of the C11 draft states:

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
>   store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
>   as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
>   punning’’).

-- Foonote 95 to 6.5.2.3 Structure and union members

Comment: I searched through the C99 spec for `union`, but I couldn't find anything about UB when reading from the non-last-set member. In what section is this rule described?

Comment: This can also be found in the C99 spec, except it also adds `This might be a trap representation.`. What does this mean?

Comment: @ninjalj: Aha, so the union trick is UB in C99: `The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances: A trap representation is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type.`

Comment: @nightcracker: a trap representation means a representation that does not correspond to a valid value. I'm not sure if `int` may actually have trap representations.

Comment: @larsmans: In the C99 specification 6.5.2.3 footnote 82: `If the member used to access the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called "type
punning"). This might be a trap representation.` Combine that with the above and you do find this trick to be _maybe_ UB (seeing that it "might" be a trap representation).

Comment: @nightcracker: yes, I'd found that out and changed the answer.

Comment: @larsmans, yes theoretically `int` can have trap representations, e.g negative `0` and stuff like that. Things like that are rare nowadays, but in anycase it is safer to do such things with `uint32_t` or whatever the width of the type you what to investigate may be.

Answer (score 1):

Your first method is not only dangerous because of aliasing but also because of alignment. `float` and `int` might have different alignment properties.

The union method is the good one, but theoretically even `unsigned int` can have trap representations. (Only on weirdo architectures, though.)

The only type that is guaranteed to not have a trap representation is `unsigned char`. And the way the standard foresees to do what you want to achieve by either having a `union` with an `unsigned char[sizeof(float)]` or by copying your object over such an array with `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty good question. The union trick is the only one I tested that works with all compilers and all warning levels. If you want to support different endianesses, probably unsigned char[4] is better than unsigned int...

As larsmans writes, there cannot be any 100% portable way to do what you want, since the underlying float implementation is not defined by any C/C++ standard.